# Mostrar query (Problema Id's diferentes)

Tags: php, query

Eu tenho uma query um pouco grande mas depois quando eu peço para mostrar ela vem com os id's misturados.

Tenho alguma coisa mal na query?

```
 SELECT *  FROM tb_detalhe_trabalhador1 inner join tb_empresa on 
tb_detalhe_trabalhador1.id = tb_empresa.id 
Inner Join tb_detalhe_trabalhador2 on tb_detalhe_trabalhador2.id = tb_empresa.id
Inner Join tb_detalhe_trabalhador3 on tb_detalhe_trabalhador3.id = tb_empresa.id
Inner Join tb_detalhe_trabalhador4 on tb_detalhe_trabalhador4.id = tb_empresa.id
Inner Join tb_detalhe_trabalhador5 on tb_detalhe_trabalhador5.id = tb_empresa.id
Inner Join tb_detalhe_trabalhador6 on tb_detalhe_trabalhador6.id = tb_empresa.id
Inner Join tb_detalhe_trabalhador7 on tb_detalhe_trabalhador7.id = tb_empresa.id
Inner Join tb_detalhe_trabalhador8 on tb_detalhe_trabalhador8.id = tb_empresa.id
Inner Join tb_detalhe_trabalhador9 on tb_detalhe_trabalhador9.id = tb_empresa.id
Inner Join tb_detalhe_trabalhador10 on tb_detalhe_trabalhador10.id = tb_empresa.id
Inner Join tb_detalhe_trabalhador11 on tb_detalhe_trabalhador11.id = tb_empresa.id
Inner Join tb_detalhe_trabalhador12 on tb_detalhe_trabalhador12.id = tb_empresa.id
Inner Join tb_detalhe_trabalhador13 on tb_detalhe_trabalhador13.id = tb_empresa.id
Inner Join tb_detalhe_trabalhador14 on tb_detalhe_trabalhador14.id = tb_empresa.id
Inner Join tb_detalhe_trabalhador15 on tb_detalhe_trabalhador15.id = tb_empresa.id
Inner Join tb_detalhe_trabalhador16 on tb_detalhe_trabalhador16.id = tb_empresa.id
Inner Join tb_equipamentos on tb_equipamentos.id = tb_empresa.id
WHERE AlvaraValidade or AcidenteValidade or SeguroValidade or FinancasValidade or 
SocialValidade or RemuneracaoValidade or InstaladorValidade or MontadorValidade or
 MedicaValidade or ProjectistaValidade or GasValidade or RedesValidade or
 SoldadorValidade or MecanicoValidade or ClasSoldadorValidade or MaquinaValidade1 or
 MaquinaValidade2 or MaquinaValidade3 or MaquinaTopoValidade BETWEEN CURDATE() AND
 CURDATE() + INTERVAL 10 DAY";

  //Faço isto primeiro
  if (($row[11] != '0000-00-00' && estaParaExpirar($row[11], "10")) 
    or ($row[12] != '0000-00-00' && estaParaExpirar($row[12], "10"))
    or ($row[13] != '0000-00-00' && estaParaExpirar($row[13], "10")) 
    or ($row[14] != '0000-00-00' && estaParaExpirar($row[14], "10")) 
    or ($row[15] != '0000-00-00' && estaParaExpirar($row[15], "10")) 
    or ($row[16] != '0000-00-00' && estaParaExpirar($row[16], "10")) 
    or ($row[17] != '0000-00-00' && estaParaExpirar($row[17], "10"))) {     
 $Nome1 = '<p>Nome: '.$row[10].'</p>' ;}
 if ($row[11] != '' && ($row[11] != NULL && ($row[11] != '0000-00-00' ))) {
 $MedicaValidade = estaParaExpirar($row[11], "10") ? '<p>
 A data da Ficha de aptidao  Medica vai expirar no dia '.$row[11].'</p>' : '';}

 //Depois no corpo do email faço so isto
 // corpo da mensagem
  $PHPMailer->Body = "<body>
  <br>
 ".$Trabalhador."
 ".$Nome1."
 ".$MedicaValidade."
```

Comment: Assumindo que a consulta está a devolver o que pretendes, no teu `SELECT`, especifica a origem dos campos, ou seja: `SELECT *  FROM tb_detalhe_trabalhador1` deverá ser algo tipo: `SELECT tb_detalhe_trabalhador1.* FROM tb_detalhe_trabalhador1` assumindo que os campos pretendidos são os da tabela `tb_detalhe_trabalhador1`.

Comment: Eu tenho. Apenas tenho para não ficar tão extenso. Mas quando eu faço para mostrar os dados ele mostra-me dados do Id 1, 4, 3,.. Quero apenas que ele mostre os dados do Id1 depois do id2 e por ai fora. Porque eu vou querer os campos de todas as tabelas

Comment: Hmmm... estarás a referir-te à ordenação dos resultados? Terminar a consulta com: `ORDER BY tb_detalhe_trabalhador1.id`.

Comment: Basta só para um ou tenho de fazer isso para todas as tabelas?

Comment: O `ORDER BY` é a ordenação dos resultados após a consulta, deverás aplicar sobre um dos campos seleccionados. No teu caso, o campo `tb_detalhe_trabalhador1.id` parece corresponder ao que pretendes.

Comment: Mas não esta a ficar a funcionar. Coloco esse código e continua-me a misturar os id's. Este código servira para selecionar os dados que serão enviados por email  e no email vem varios id's . Quero que cada email tenha os dados do seu id

Comment: Se contratarem o 17 o RH precisa te avisar para mudar a query , normalize esta tabela.

Comment: mas não vai ter mais. Pediram só para colocar 16.

Comment: Você criou uma tabela para cada funcionário?

Comment: quais são as colunas das tabelas?

Answer (score 4):

## Imagino que seus joins estejam errados:

tb_detalhe_trabalhador1.id = tb_empresa.id 
tb_equipamentos.id = tb_empresa.id

#### tb_empresa

id nome_empresa 
1  SamSumg 
2 HP 
3  Dell

#### tb_equipamentos

id   equipamento
1    computador
2    laptop
3    scanner

#### tb_detalhe_trabalhador1

id  nome
1   Joao
2   Maria
3   Pedro

Você deve atentar-se quais são as chaves primarias e relacioná-las corretamente.
tb_detalhe_trabalhador.id_empresa = empresa.id
tb_equipamentos.id_empresa = empresa.id

Tente fazer os INNER JOINS e os WHERE aos poucos, de preferencia tabela por tabela para certificar-se que os resultados estão correspondendo ao esperado.

Comment: mas eu testei a query no mysql e funciona correctamente. Mostra os dados todos como query. Ao enviar o email é que os ids ficam em alguns sitios ficam trocados

Answer (score 2):

Conforme a exclamação do Sr. @Motta, o correto é fazer UMA tabela para registrar os detalhes de cada trabalhador assim sendo mesma regra para a tabela onde registra os equipamentos, e empresa ( supondo que ali você registre as filias, matriz etc).

Após a normalização, faça uma consulta condicionando tb_trabalhador, tb_equipamentos, tb_empresa através de suas respectivas chaves Pk e/ou Fk e o ultimo filtro between para pegar entre o período desejado.

Comment: tive a ver como mostro os dados. 
é possivel em campos null ele ir buscar o id de outra id preenchida?

Comment: sim usando o join ou union ele busca resultados null.

Comment: Imaginando ".$Exempl0." ".$Exemplo2." um deles está null . Exemplo. id2, (Vazio = NULL) ele pode ir buscar o dados ao id 3 por o id estar vazio?

Comment: Quando existem resultados NULL é usado Left Join

Answer (score 2):

Primeiramente, normalize seu banco de dados. Mesmo que a empresa ou departamento só vai ter 16 funcionários, é uma prática muito ruim ficar com 16 tabelas em seu banco de dados, pois se um outro programador tiver que mexer em seu sistema ou criar um outro programa que utilize seu banco, ele com certeza irá se perder, e o desempenho do banco de dados em si será comprometido pelo excesso de tabelas.

OBS.: Normalização é a pré-organização dos dados e a separação e retirada de dados duplicados. [Wikipedia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_dados) e [Microsoft(Inglês)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/283878)

Depois de ter normalizado o banco, recrie a sua query de acordo com as novas tabelas criadas na normallização. Além de ficar muito mais legível, aumenta o desempenho de sua aplicação.

E então, finalmente, use a cláusula `ORDER BY` para organizar os resultados da query.