# Fatal error: Maximum execution

Tags: php, timeout

Surgiu-me um erro ao executar um código no Php

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

```
$validade = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
```

O código funciona todo na perfeição. só que aparece-me esse código no final. 
Não é que me incomode mas só para tentar resolver

o Loop:

```
For ($contador = 0; $contador = 1; $contador++){
```

Comment: Se você simplesmente aumentar o tempo limite vai resolver a mensagem de erro, mas estará mascarando o problema real,  tem que descobrir qual é o processo pesado e tentar otimiza-lo, pois se deixar assim pode ter certeza que terá problemas de sobrecarga no servidor, que pode resultar até em suspensão do serviço...

Comment: O @Jader tem razão. Pode colocar a sua query aqui, talvez aí esteja o erro.

Comment: Observando suas perguntas anteriores, acredito que o problema é a query: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28815/mostrar-query-problema-ids-diferentes

Comment: Tem cara de ser erro em loop sem fim... Não retornou a linha?

Comment: Unico loop possivel For ($contador = 0; $contador = 1; $contador++){

Comment: É o loop mesmo, veja como montar um laço [**for**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.for.php), você não informou qual o critério do seu loop.

Answer (score 5):

Acho estranho dizer que o código funciona na perfeição, pois dá uma "fatal error" o que quer dizer que o engine parou de processar o script devido a um erro. E diz que parou de processar porque ele demora mais de 30 segundos para ser executado. Muita pouca gente tem paciência para esperar meio minuto pela resposta do servidor. Por isso, acho melhor ver onde está o problema que faz o script demorar tanto tempo a ser executado, em vez de permitir mais tempo de execução.

Answer (score 1):

O seu loop esta errado.

No segundo parametro do `for` utilize `==` ao invés de `=`.

Do jeito que você fez ele está sempre mudando o valor da variável `$contador` para 1 e nunca sai do `for`, gerando um loop infinito.

```
for($contador = 0; $contador == 1; $contador++){
```

Answer (score 0):

O seu código está demorando mais que 30 segundos para ser executado!

Você pode aumentar o tempo limite de execução com a função [set_time_limit(segundos)](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.set-time-limit.php).